# Computer restarts with large mini batches in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am running TensorFlow for Windows with a Titan X GPU (12 GB memory). When I try to train a network for images of 256X256X1 with mini-batches larger than 50 images, my computer just crashes and restarts automatically. With smaller mini-batches it runs just fine.
Any clues on what might be causing this?

Comment: The only guess I'd have is that something is wrong with your RAM. Check it like described in [this post](http://superuser.com/a/425537/348793).

Comment: you might want to `nvidia-smi` to see your GPU utility. Increase batch size gradually and monitor how GPU resources are consumed.

Comment: What your network looks like is more important than your batch size. Can you post more information here? If you have huge fully connected layers at the end... I guess you're running out of memory or something.

Comment: I've seen computers freeze when TF tries to allocate too much CPU memory. So you could check how much CPU RAM you are using

Comment: Please post more information, including host/device ram/processor usage, network parameter size, network structure etc.

Comment: I'm using the generic MNIST network provided in the TensorFlow website, so I don't think that's choking my memory... I did see, however, that once I build my network the memory usage in my GPU climbs from 200 MB to 11.8 GB... is that normal?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, it included buying a new PC with a new PSU...

Answer (score 2):

I've seen similar problems being discussed in some gaming forums, where the PC would just shut down when the GPU was under heavy load. The reason was usually that the GPU was drawing more power than the power supply unit could handle. Check e.g. [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2415941/restarts-high-gpu-load.html) or [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2681174/restart-immediately-heavy-gpu-usage.html). So may be it's worth investigating whether your PSU is the culprit.

Edit: May be the program SpeedFan can help you debugging this - it is able to show both voltages and readings of temperature sensors, which would also tell you if your PC is overheating (I've never used the tool myself, and I'm not affiliated with it either, just found it online).