# Training NN in ubuntu with tensorflow gpu makes computer restart

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, neural-network

I run tensorflow program in ubuntu with gpu. After one iteration, and the computer system restart with no warning or error messages. If I use cpu to train, the program would run successfully.

I check the power, not the reason. And the temperature was not high. And the GPU memory was not exhausted.

The tensorflow version is showed below.

[image]

Comment: When you say you checked the temperature, can you clarify how you did that? Did you check the GPU temperature using `nvidia-smi`? It sure sounds like you might be overheating the GPU.

Comment: Before the system restart, nvidia-smi shows like this [screenshot](https://t1.picb.cc/uploads/2018/06/29/2Dx2ZJ.png)

Comment: You don't appear to be using the GPU (very cool and 0% utilization). Are you processing on the CPU? How is the CPU temp?

Comment: It could be hardware problem, for example, if your power supply was not enough for the GPU. No way we can debug this for you.

Comment: Today, I use UPS as power supply. The system still shutdown. The reason may be other hardware problem, not power supply. I am going to give it up.

Comment: rey lowering the batch size. It works for [some](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8858) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41237115/786559) (2 links)